# How to set the export dimensions in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png, resolution, dimensions

I have used illustrator for quite a while now and every time I export my vectors as png's, they export into the most ridiculous resolutions you would ever see. For example, I just exported a png about 20 minutes ago, it has 13 artboards (4x3 with one at the bottom) and the final resolution it exported in was just over 60,000 x 60,000!! I can't even preview the file...soo, how can I change the dimensions that illustrator exports the file to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While exporting: Click "use artboards" before you click the save button

[image: Check the 'Use Artboards' box to get all artboards exported individually]

Otherwise it will export the total range of space you have (in total). Notice the preview thumbnail in the below examples.

[image: Example: Artboards not selected on previous page]

I'd post more screenshots but i'm lower than 10 reputation right now.

Comment: Thanks, could you post the screenshots on something like imgur?

Comment: Yes. I'll have them up in a few hours. On my commute back home. I'll edit this post later tonight with the link.

Comment: [note to self, don't press 'return' on this website haha. Sorry for the notifications. Here is the imgur album: http://imgur.com/a/x9MvC